# "utf-8" encoding works on development server but not when deployed

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8, pythonanywhere

My Django application hosted at pythonanywhere.com does not support utf-8 encoding. Characters like 'é' return error.

**Views**:

```
def result_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search = request.POST.get('textfield').encode("utf-8")
        print search

        try:
            try:
                value = wikipedia.page(search)
                title = value.title
                url = value.url
                print title
                data = wikipedia.summary(search, sentences=10)

            except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
                data = e
                title = search + " (Disambiguation)"
                u = search.replace(" ", "_")
                url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + u

        except:
            raise Http404()

        return render(request, "search/result.html", {'title': title, 'url': url, 'data': data})

    else:
        return render(request, "search/result.html", {})
```

The `textfield` input is encoded with utf-8 and works fine in Django development server but returns 404 page in my `pythonanywhere` server.

**Template**:

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" action="{% url 'result' %}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="textfield" placeholder="Search" required/>
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg ">Search</button>
</form>
```

Comment: I believe that you have to allow the DB used by Pythonanyhere ( It Should be MySQL, but that could have been changed)  to use encoding utf-8.

Comment: your outer try/except/404 is swallowing the real error.   get rid of it and see what the actual traceback is in the logs?  it may not be to do with any kind of database...

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow the DB used by Pythonanyhere ( It Should be MySQL as from [here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DatabaseCharacterSets/) but that could have been changed)  to use encoding utf-8, to do this, simply start a MySQL console, then run the following command (replacing databasename with your database's name, of course):

```
 ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Then, for each table run this:

```
 ALTER TABLE tablename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Utf-8 is the standard encoding used to store non Latin characters(eg. Cyrillic) in a DB then you'll need to change its character set and collation settings, firstly on your database and then secondly on each table.

If you have many table you could do those command with a stored procedure.

Comment: I believe this is for database driven applications. My application does not need a database. It just requests the user input through the Wikipedia API. So when the user input has special characters it works fine in development server but not in production.

Comment: "works fine in Django development server" so basically you are saying you take out the string telling Django what DB use(by default its SQLlite instance). Moreover "My Django application hosted at pythonanywhere.com does not support utf-8 encoding" it's not about your application but where are you "hosting it", and probably 100% they do use a DB, that as from the link it's a MYSQL instance and they officially state how by deafault is the 
Database character sets. Data are stored in DB for persistance. By the way I tried to be useful, give it a try.